# Generic Scala library for matching and constraining values

Tags: scala, dsl

I'd need a generic way of matching/constraining values in runtime. Let say you have a stream of data (from CSV file for instance) and a set of constraints on entries ( created > 20150213, title contains "foo", visits > 100) supplied by user via REST parameters or by some scala DSL.

I'd just need to abstract over scala collection filtering operation so that `Iterable#filter` method would accept a matcher that would be constructed declaratively.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a general solution to this problem. There are :

- SQL/Relational query DSLs
- url path matchers (akka-http)
- form validation (play framework)
- a lot of value matchers in scala testing frameworks
- a lot of DB drivers implement these (mongo, elasticSearch)
- it might be extracted from one of serialization libraries, but I haven't found any with this support.

Currently I have a feeling that I'll have to write my own, starting by covering the basic types (String, primitives, Date) and operations (<,>,<=,>=, regex) etc. But I might be a millionth person that is actually inventing a wheel...

Comment: The tedious part, in my experience, is to convert the stream (e.g., csv rows) into case class instances (or similar).   I have played around with scala language.dynamics to add a generic layer, using converted column names as field names, but .csv files sometimes don't have a column names row, and sometimes they can have bizarre column names (e.g., embedded newlines and such).  What constraints can we assume will apply to the input stream?